# Force usage of packages.config in VisualStudio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Visual Studio doesn't see all installed packages in packages.config files.

So restore command not working.

I have no idea why. Need a bit of assistance.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. And l want to know whether you have any concern about this issue. If you have any issues, we are willing to help you further. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio doesn't see all installed packages in packages.config
>   files. So restore command not working.I have no idea why. Need a bit
>   of assistance.

In fact, when you use packages.config to install nuget packages, all of packages and their dependencies are stored in the `packages.config` file.

I guess that you might drop some dependencies of the nuget packages in the `packages.config` file or `xxxx.csproj`. In this situation, `Restore nuget packages` will not restore the dependencies of the nuget packages.

**The only solution** is to reinstall nuget packages:

Please click `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`--> `Package Manager Console`-->input `update-Package -reinstall`

[image]

And after that, you will see all of them in the `packages.config` file.